# powershell get-eventlog add if more than 5 times

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, eventlog-source, get-eventlog

I am using:

```
"%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" $log=Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceID  4625 -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-60); if (($log)) {Write-Output $log[0].Message} ELSE {Write-Output 'WARNING-NoEventFound'}
```

This works perfect for me. I want to expand if possible and say write the output if the event happened more than 5 times. Similar to:

Count(*) > 5 that I would use in SQL.

Comment: $log has a `.count` property you can check. `If ($log.count -gt 5){"whatever"}`

Comment: This worked perfect. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention an alternative to Get-EventLog: [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1)

It usually has a lot better performance, both locally and over the network, it can do server side filtering with `-FilterHashTable` before sending the results. This can come in handy since Active Directory logs can be quite large sometimes.

Since you're only interested in if it's >5 results or not, we can also speed it up by breaking early when we have found 6 results, using `-MaxEvents`, and then just check whether we found 6 events or not.

```
$maxEvents = 6
$filterHashtable = @{
    LogName   = 'Security'
    Id        = 4625
    StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
}

$log = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filterHashtable -MaxEvents $maxEvents
if ($log.Count -ge $maxEvents) {
    #your code here
```

For readability I prefer to have the hashtable in a variable, but it can also be written inline like this, with `;` as separator for the key value pairs:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName = 'Security'; Id = ... }
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late response, thanks for the update. This also helped. The reason I was using Get-EventLog is when I try to use Get-WinEvent on 2003 and 2008 non R2 servers, it would fail on me. When I ran your Get-WinEvent command, it worked perfect on our 2012-2016 servers. Thanks again.